# 401 Unauthorized - Exception

Tags: fiware-orion

I face a problem today regarding the connectivity with Orion public instance @http://orion.lab.fi-ware.org:1026/ngsi10/contextEntities/{entity_id}. While, two days ago, I got always connection to the orion public instance, always by using the same Authentication Token, I got from FI-WARE, Today when I'm trying to connect I get an error: "GET http://orion.lab.fi-ware.org:1026/ngsi10/contextEntities/urn:smartsantander:testbed:3337 returned a response status of 401 Unauthorized".

I was and continue to use the Jersey REST API so as to connect with NGS10 Orion REST API Implementation.

Is there any idea about what I have to do to solve the problem? Is this a problem in Orion Server side with the Authentication Service?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the token has expired. You can re-generated a fresh token runing the token_script.sh script, as described in [the following document](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Quick_Start_for_Programmers).

**EDIT:** the normal behaviour of the system is to cancel the token from time to time, so the best approach is regenerate it with a given periodicity (e.g. 24 hours). However, note that although you can manually regenerate the token and recofigure your application to use the new one as described above, it is better to program your application to do it automatically.

Please, have a look to the [OAuth course in FI-WARE education platform](http://edu.fi-ware.org/course/view.php?id=63) and [the Refresh Token section in the OAuth 2.0 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5) for more information.